# Updating TextView from DatePicker

Tags: java, android, function, static, datepicker

I am trying to update a TextView from inside a Datepicker, however I am getting the error

"non-static method (updateDateTextView(long)) can not be referenced from a static context"

Here is my DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        AddItem.updateDateTextView(timestamp);
    }
}
```

Here is my function inside AddItem.java which is an Activity.

```
      public  class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context ctx = this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public void updateDateTextView(long timestamp){
        TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
        textViewToChange.setText(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: you are calling the method updateDateTextView from a static method... post the MCVE please....

Comment: I have added a MCVE to the original post

Answer (score 2):

As they said you can't call non-static method like static method. Try this:

Implements the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` and the logic in your Activity:

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    showDatePickerDialog();
}

public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.init(this, this);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date_picker");
}

public void updateDateTextView(long timestamp){
    TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openDate);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    textViewToChange.setText(date);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        updateDateTextView(timestamp);
}
```

And initialize the DatePicker with the listener, the class should look like this:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;
    Context context;

    public void init(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(context, listener, year, month, day);
    }

}
```

I tried, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        AddItem.updateDateTextView(timestamp); ///Here is the error
    }
```

the error is that **AddITem.updateDateTextView** is wrong. the method updateDateTextView is not static.

you need to start that Activity with an Intent and the somewhere in the lifecycle call the method `updateDateTextView`

**or**

modify the method and make it static (but that is not so good developer idea)

```
public static void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
```

Comment: How can i not call it from a static method?

Answer (score 0):

A non-static method can not be used with a static class
try to change the

`public void updateDateTextView(long timestamp){
    .....
}`

to

```
public static void updateDateTextView(long timestamp){
...}
```

Comment: Doing this causes an error inside the updateDateTextView() function with the findViewByID, The error is the same - "non-static method (findViewById(int)) can not be referenced from a static context

Comment: are you trying to access the datepicker tittle?

Comment: I am trying to update a TextView in the AddItem activity with the value of the DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one can define an [interface](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-an-interface-in-java.html) in the DatePickerFragment class as in the code bellow.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

DateChooserListenerHandler dateChooserListenerHandler;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    //Note this is where the updateTextView method in the interface is invoked from
    ((DateChooserListenerHandler) getActivity()).updateTextView(timestamp);
}

//Define an interface with a method that takes long, it will be overridden by classes that implement the interface
public interface DateChooserListenerHandler{

    public void updateTextView(long s);
}
```

}

The AddItem activity class can then implement the the interface like in the code bellow.

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.DateChooserListenerHandler {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

//The overridden method from the interface defined in DatePickerFragment class
@Override
public void updateTextView(long s) {
    updateDateTextView(s);
}

public void updateDateTextView(long timestamp){
    TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    textViewToChange.setText(date);
}
```

}

That works fine for me however, I have not examined its performance implications on the app but I find it easier.
In case you just wanted to update a TextView directly from the DatePickerFragment then you could do it like bellow.

```
 @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(timestamp + "");
}
```